# How to re-train an existing spacy NER model for currency

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to update an existing spacy model "en_core_web_sm" with some different country currency such as "euro", "rupees", "eu", "Rs.", "INR" etc. How can I achieve that ? The spacy tutorial didn't quite help me as training a fixed string such as "horses" as "ANIMAL" seems different than my requirements. The reason is I can have currency value indifferent formats : "1 million euros", "Rs. 10,000", "INR 1 thousand" etc. My sample dataset contains around  1000 samples with the following format :

```
TRAIN_DATA = [      
 (" You have activated International transaction limit for Debit Card ending XXXX1137 on 2017-07-05 12:48:20.0 via NetBanking. The new limit is Rs. 250,000.00", {'entities' : [(140, 154, 'MONEY')] }),...
]
```

Can anyone please help me out with this with the data format, training size or any other relevant information ?

Comment: why adding ANIMAL model didn't help you?

Comment: ANIMAL model was working fine even with a few datasets, but the money model didn't work. I guess this money model requires to learn about all kinds of number format or something like that which I am not quite sure about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example from the documentation should work for you. I altered it a little to match your variable name.

```
optimizer = nlp.begin_training()

for itn in range(100):
    random.shuffle(train_data)
    for raw_text, entity_offsets in TRAIN_DATA:
        doc = nlp.make_doc(raw_text)
        gold = GoldParse(doc, entities=entity_offsets)
        nlp.update([doc], [gold], drop=0.5, sgd=optimizer)
nlp.to_disk('/model')
```

[Link to Documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/training)